# SELECT Statement PDO adding a variable to a ORDER BY clause

Tags: php, select, pdo

I am trying to add the option to choose what to order a SELECT statement by using a drop down list. My previously working SELECT statement would select the data from my table and just order by points. Now I want to be able to order by points, or goals, or assists etc etc.

Here is my previously working statement:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT player_stats.*, teams.*
                       FROM player_stats
                       LEFT JOIN teams ON player_stats.tid = teams.teamid
                       WHERE season = :season
                       ORDER BY points DESC
                       LIMIT 20");
$query->bindParam(':season', $season);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Previously working Form:

```
<form action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="get" id="search">
    <select name='statsYear' id='statsYear' class='dropDown' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option <?php if (($_GET['statsYear'] == '20162017') || !isset($_GET['statsYear'])) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20162017">2016-2017</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20152016') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20152016">2015-2016</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20142015') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20142015">2014-2015</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20132014') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20132014">2013-2014</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20122013') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20122013">2012-2013</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Here is my new SELECT stament that is giving the incorrect output. I will share a link to the incorrect output later on:**

```
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT player_stats.*, teams.*
                           FROM player_stats
                           LEFT JOIN teams ON player_stats.tid = teams.teamid
                           WHERE season = :season
                           ORDER BY  :statstype DESC
                           LIMIT 20");
    $query->bindParam(':season', $season);
    $query->bindParam(':statstype', $statsType);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
  echoTable($result);
```

**The query above does not recognize the new `$statsType` variable. This is where I need help. Here is my new form and variable declaration for reference:**

```
if (isset($_GET['statsType'])) {
    $statsType = $_GET['statsType'];
} else {    
    $statsType = 'points' ;
}

<form action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="get" id="search">
    <select name='statsYear' id='statsYear' class='dropDown' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option <?php if (($_GET['statsYear'] == '20162017') || !isset($_GET['statsYear'])) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20162017">2016-2017</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20152016') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20152016">2015-2016</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20142015') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20142015">2014-2015</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20132014') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20132014">2013-2014</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsYear'] == '20122013') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="20122013">2012-2013</option>
    </select>
        <select  name="statsType" id="statsType" class="dropDown" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsType'] == 'points'  || !isset($_GET['statsType'])) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?> value="points">Points</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsType'] == 'goals') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?> value="goals">Goals</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsType'] == 'assists') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="assists">Assists</option>
        <option <?php if (($_GET['statsType'] == 'pim') ) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="pim">PIM</option>
        <option <?php if ($_GET['statsType'] == 'pm') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="pm">+/-</option>
        <option <?php if (($_GET['statsType'] == 'toi') ) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="toi">TOI</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**This is what the query should look like if I select assists in the form:** 
[image: correct output]
**This is the actual output:** 
http://sjsharktank.com/leaders.php?statsYear=20162017&statsType=assists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use param for column .. you should use (eventually) string concatenationand build sql command dinamically

but be careful for sql injection

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT player_stats.*, teams.*
                           FROM player_stats
                           LEFT JOIN teams ON player_stats.tid = teams.teamid
                           WHERE season = :season
                           ORDER BY  " . $statstype  . " DESC
                           LIMIT 20");
```

if you can use double quote for nestings quote limit use alway the same

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT player_stats.*, teams.*
                           FROM player_stats
                           LEFT JOIN teams ON player_stats.tid = teams.teamid
                           WHERE season = :season
                           ORDER BY  ' . $statstype  . ' DESC
                           LIMIT 20');
```

you can also work with double quote and php magic behavior for vars

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT player_stats.*, teams.*
                           FROM player_stats
                           LEFT JOIN teams ON player_stats.tid = teams.teamid
                           WHERE season = :season
                           ORDER BY  $statstype   DESC
                           LIMIT 20");
```

Comment: I had to add single quotes for nesting reasons, but this doesn't seem to be changing anything. Edit: I removed the " .  . " and it works, but now I have that whole SQL injection think you mentioned as a problem.

Comment: why  you have to add single quotes ?  are your sure you have a correct value in $statstype .. (try var_dump($statstype)  .  and check also the final query command  var_dump($query)

Comment: I have update the answer with single quote  (don't mixin )

Comment: Neither of the quote options worked for me actually.

Comment: Could be you code  have some features that are in conflict with the quotes sequence .. looking at the code you provided i can't evaluate this aspect   . should work with double quotes and vars ..

Comment: I must have had a syntax error somewhere the first time I tried. The error log was telling me I was trying to Order the column DESC. I tried again with quotes and it worked. So it worked with and without quotes for me. I'll accept this answer now. Thank you.